# Using cashier capabilities without stripe?

Tags: laravel, paypal, laravel-cashier

Stripe and Braintree are not available in my location, so I've to use Paypal.

I'm trying to figure out **the technicalities and best practices** , since it's my first time integrating payments.

I'm also trying to figure how to smoothly go from a register + free access, to register + pay to access

**Questions:**

- I want to make it a smooth transition when I decide to start charging my users for access. What do I need to set-up beforehand? Currently I haven't launched yet so I want to prepare everything I need.
- Can I use cashier to manage access for users that paid but while I'm using paypal and not stripe like cashier use? (i mean to use some of cashier functionality).

note: I found a package on github (https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-paypal) that integrates paypal into a laravel app, but it uses a deprecated api from 2017.